# Django - cooperation of two users

Tags: django, django-users

I'm developing a Django web app and have run into the following problem.

The idea I have is to allow two users to perform an action together on the certain page - when first one enters the page the "session" is created and the server is waiting for the second user to enter. After 2nd user enters the page, they can perform a certain action together.
(Basically they will take turns choosing items from available item pool, so that in the end everyone has his "basket")

Could you share any resources on how to achieve this functionality with Django? Any documentation/tutorials/materials/tips what to look for will be useful. I wasn't able to find anything, but I probably don't name the problem properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to find an exact project like it. You have to solve it on your own. I think You can solve this problem with **Django Channels** (https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/index.html)

Comment: Actually I thought that it's quite a popular issue and I'm just not able to name it. Thanks for the link, surely something to begin with :)